# Coming anchors with query

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a single page website using anchors.
So far i got 3 sections:

- home (index.php)
- photography (gallery) (index.php#photgraphy)
- about (index.php#about)

This function reads the root folder for sub folders (categories).

```
    function photo_menu($gall_dir) {
     $return = NULL;
      $cat_dir = scandir($gall_dir);
       foreach($cat_dir as $cat) {
        if(is_dir("$gall_dir/$cat")) {
         if($cat !== '.' && $cat !== '..') {
          $return .= '<a href=#photography?cat=' . $cat .' class="photo_menu">' . $cat . '</a>' . PHP_EOL;
          }     
         }
        }
       return $return;
      }
```

De function that i'm trying to make is supposed to get the category from the url via.

And that is where i run into trouble.

Is there a way to combine the query with the anchors or is there an alternative to what i'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More an HTML question than PHP.

Always put the anchor last.

```
$return.='<a href="index.php?cat='.$cat.'#photography" class="photo_menu">'.$cat.'</a>';
```

Comment: Well that was pretty awkward. 
I've read about how everything after the # is client side but putting the anchors at the end of the url never crossed my mind...

Thanks for your help.